# What is the Protestant explanation for how Mary could provide Jesus with his flesh but be part of the fall herself?

Tags: life-of-jesus, protestantism, virgin-mary, original-sin, incarnation

What supporting arguments do Protestants offer for Mary being sinful, yet providing Jesus with his flesh and blood body; how do they believe Jesus could be born from a sinful Mary and not inherit the effects of the fall from her?

By the effects of the 'fall', I mean what the first couple's sin caused to happen to the whole creation. This includes animals beginning to eat each other when previously they were vegetarians, vegetation changed to include thorns and thistles, the ground becoming hard to work with labour of sweat replacing previous tasks which did not result in perspiration, begetting children changed to include labour which induces sweat, when the implication is it would not have prior to the 'fall'. Additionally, marriage relationships changed to include the woman being ruled over (possibly dominated?) by the man without this changing her desire for him. Satan began to have his own 'seed' progeny, referred to by Jesus in the gospels by his saying, 'your father the devil'.

It is my understanding that Protestants believe the scripture text which says Mary conceived Jesus in her womb, indicating that she supplied the genetic material that any other woman would while conceiving a child. This means Mary gave Jesus her flesh, (egg) to fulfil the scripture which states that Jesus was the bloodline(flesh and blood) of King David (e.g. in the [Gospel of Matthew's genealogy](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Matthew+1%3A1-17&version=NRSV).)

Also, could people give me some advice on voting as I am new: do I have to do the voting? What if I'm not satisfied with the answer? Each answer gives information and food for thought but I don't think it fully answers the question.

Comment: This is already answered [here](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/4789/how-can-jesus-born-of-mankind-be-sinless).

Comment: Hello, you are saying your personal beliefs as if all protestants believe them, which is not true. I do not believe that Mary gave an egg which became Jesus.