# Age of accountability?

Tags: sin, heaven, hell, death

I have been raised in Prodestant church all of my life and I have heard several times from members of various churches about an age of accountability—which is an age once a person reaches it they are solely acountable for their own sins. For example, if they died before reaching this age they wouldn't go to hell for any sins they have commited. I have heard various ages for this such as 10 and 13. Considering this my question is:

Is there scriptural evidence that states the age of acountablality? Does it even exist?

Comment: Brother *mikey*, no, there isn't. In Protestant traditions the doctrine of the “age ofaccountability” has been added to the canon of Scripture as a dogma even though it is not found in any Scripture.

Comment: Good news, this has already been asked, so you don't need to wait for answers.   [Basis for the concept of an "Age of accountability"](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/8557/basis-for-the-concept-of-an-age-of-accountability)

Comment: I did not find the answers to the original question very satisfying.  In fact, the most important teaching in regard to the age of accountability was not even addressed in those answers.  For this reason, I'll refer you to my answer, posted at the original question.  Don

Answer (score -2):

We are accountable for our actions, words, teachings and judging.
No such thing for age accountability.

it is just another man made doctrine to bound people by their laws, doctrine and beliefs.

> Matthew 12:35-37 ESV
>   The good person out of his good treasure brings forth good, and the evil person out of his evil treasure brings forth evil. I tell you, on the day of judgment people will give account for every careless word they speak, for by your words you will be justified, and by your words you will be condemned.”

Unbelievers will give an account

> Romans 14:10-12 ESV
>   Why do you pass judgment on your brother? Or you, why do you despise your brother? For we will all stand before the judgment seat of God; for it is written, “As I live, says the Lord, every knee shall bow to me, and every tongue shall confess to God.” So then each of us will give an account of himself to God.

Let the people who judge give an account for their judging

God Bless

Comment: I find amusing that you say "just another man made doctrine". How different is this doctrine from the others in the Bible? Couldn't the Age of Accountability be also a revelation?

Comment: all nothing but uncreditable words.
Show us where it says in the bible about age accountability, then we'll understand and listen.
If you cannot provide then age accountability is nothing but man made doctrine.

Comment: like Uzzah looking into the Ark?

Comment: yes...and God being a LOVING God for killing someone correcting something.