# According to Reformed Theology, why do unbelievers deserve punishment?

Tags: reformed-theology, free-will, calvin, punishment, determinism

I read this quote from John Calvin on [some website](http://www.reformationtheology.com/2007/08/compatibilistic_determinism.php):

> "...we allow that **man has choice and that it is self-determined, so that if he does anything evil, it should be imputed to him and to his own voluntary choosing**. We do away with coercion and force, because this contradicts the nature of the will and cannot coexist with it. **We deny that choice is free**, because through man's innate wickedness it is of necessity driven to what is evil and cannot seek anything but evil. And from this it is possible to deduce what a great difference there is between necessity and coercion. For we do not say that man is dragged unwillingly into sinning, but that because his will is corrupt he is held captive under the yoke of sin and therefore of necessity will in an evil way. For where there is bondage, there is necessity. But it makes a great difference whether the bondage is voluntary or coerced. We locate the necessity to sin precisely in corruption of the will, from which follows that it is self-determined. John Calvin from Bondage and Liberation of the Will, pg. 69-70

I believe in determinism, and I have no problem with the idea that humans *need* to be chastised for bad behavior. For example, a child steals a candy bar. The mother catches the child, makes them return the candy and apologize, and then issues whatever *corrective* chastisement to *cause* the child to think twice next time they want to steal.

I also have no problem with the fact that God appointed for this to happen, so that the child's will was not free. The child stealing and then getting chastised is a good lesson to both the child and others about the consequences of sin, and this lesson will *cause* them to behave appropriately (as well as continue the chain of determinism towards God's ultimate goal). Had the child never stolen, then the chastisement would have never occurred, and nobody would have learned any prudence.

What I don't understand is why the child *deserves* to be *punished*, namely in an eternal hell with flesh burning (or whatever other ideas are associated with this place.)

According to Reformed Theology, why do humans *deserve* to be *punished* forever in hell for their predetermined actions?

Comment: It appears that you are asking for an argument based on contradictory premises - Calvin is denying determinism, but you want an argument based on it??

Comment: @bruisedreed Hmm...I thought Calvin believed in Compatabilism, which by definition means freewill (with a special definition) is *compatible* with *determinism*.

Comment: Are you asking about the "T" in Tulip.  Limited atonement, only the select will be saved.  My understanding, according to Calvin's subjective teaching, is that the child was created for destruction.  It is God's will that this child burns, and another, who he chose, does not.  It's actually a comforting position if you are a Calvinist.

Comment: @Marc Yes I think Limited Atonement will probably need to be brought up in an answer, because my question is about those outside of this "limited" group, and why they *deserve* to burn forever. *Deserve* is the main subject, so it's about why unbelievers *deserve*, rather than *ought to* be punished. A child *ought to* be punished, but nobody *ought to* burn forever. They have to *deserve* something that severe.

Comment: "Deserve is the main subject, so it's about why unbelievers deserve, rather than ought to be punished. " -- Note that in Reformed theology, both believers and non believers, the elect and the non elect, *deserve* eternal punishment.

Comment: Perhaps my initial comment would have been less confusing if I had included "strict" before determinism. The initial sentence in your quote is a denial of strict determinism. The second section that you have bolded does indeed indicate a compatibilist position. The problem I see with your question is that when I analyze it's form, it seems that *you* are actually assuming a strict determinist position with your premises.

Comment: In other words, why is it that the first sentence in the quote is not already a satisfactory answer to your question?

Comment: @bruisedreed The world works the exact same way for both Determinism and Compatiblism. Please see my answer to [What is the difference between hard determinism and compatibilism, under the assumption of physicalism?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/a/38068/22377)

Comment: I don't understand the first sentence of your last comment at all. Regarding your link, your answer there exactly mirrors my point. I don't see how the same person can both write that answer and ask this question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simple answer is that God has decided that the wages of sin is death. It is entirely up to God as to what punishment sin deserves, and the punishment God chose was eternal damnation.

The Heidelberg Catechism's first section on Sin and Misery speaks about this, in particular question and answer 10:

> Q. Does God permit
>   such disobedience and rebellion
>   to go unpunished?
>
> A. Certainly not.
>   God is terribly angry
>   with the sin we are born with
>   as well as the sins we personally commit.
>   As a just judge,
>   God will punish them both now and in eternity,
>   having declared:
>   “Cursed is everyone who does not observe and obey
>   all the things written in the book of the law.”

The Westminster Larger Catechism also mentions this, in question 29 in particular but previous questions too:

> Q. 29. What are the punishments of sin in the world to come?
>
> A. The punishments of sin in the world to come, are everlasting separation from the comfortable presence of God, and most grievous torments in soul and body, without intermission, in hell-fire forever.

And also question 89:

> Q. 89. What shall be done to the wicked at the day of judgment?
>
> A. At the day of judgment, the wicked shall be set on Christ’s left hand, and, upon clear evidence, and full conviction of their own consciences, shall have the fearful but just sentence of condemnation pronounced against them; and thereupon shall be cast out from the favourable presence of God, and the glorious fellowship with Christ, his saints, and all his holy angels, into hell, to be punished with unspeakable torments, both of body and soul, with the devil and his angels forever.

And also question 152:

> Q. 152. What doth every sin deserve at the hands of God?
>
> A. Every sin, even the least, being against the sovereignty, goodness, and holiness of God, and against his righteous law, deserveth his wrath and curse, both in this life, and that which is to come; and cannot be expiated but by the blood of Christ.

Comment: Great answer Also, we must think about this. Who you commit a crime against plays a role in how severe the punishment is. If i punch you (or any random person) i might pay a fine, maybe spend a night in jail (if anything at all) But if i punch the president of the united states, i might get killed on the spot, or do some serious time in prison. All our sins are against an Eternal, Holy God. Therefore the punishments are Eternally severe.

Comment: Okay do you mean to say that people *deserve* to be punished because God has decreed that people *deserve* this punishment, regardless whether the person had any free choice in the matter,  and no other reason is necessary?

Comment: @anonymouswho Yes, essentially. Much the same as how sins are sins because God has decreed that they are sins; we don't need any further reason.

Comment: @Birdie So sin isn't so much against the nature and will of God intrinsically, nor death (a consequence and punishment for sin), but sin and its fruit are the will of God? Rape and murder and thiefing and people burning for eternity is the will of God in a direct sense? God does *not* desire that all are saved and come to a knowledge of the truth? Also, why does God "not take pleasure in the death of the wicked" if it is precisely His will that the wicked are punished?

Comment: I.e. if God would "rather they turn from their wicked ways and live", why did He 'eternally decree' they would do the exact opposite?

Comment: @SolaGratia Reformed theology distinguishes among the decretive will of God, the preceptive will of God, and the will of disposition of God. The decretive will of God is where God makes things come to pass that He has decreed will come to pass. The preceptive will of God is the revealed law of God which He wills that all men follow (but doesn't force people to follow, thus not His decretive will). The will of disposition is what God finds pleasing.

Comment: It doesn't please Him for the wicked to die, but He does decree that the wicked should die. He commands everyone to be saved (preceptive will), and would be pleased for everyone to be saved (will of disposition) but does not decree that everyone will be saved (decretive will).

Comment: "The preceptive will of God is the revealed law of God which He wills that all men follow (but doesn't force people to follow, thus not His decretive will)."

Does He not 'decree' their wills and fate? If He does, then that is definitionally making them helpless/forcing them. To His 'perceptive will'?

If "It doesn't please Him for the wicked to die," why would He decree it that this or that man choose to do evil, if it doesn't please Him? It's tantamount to God defying Himself (another of His 'wills'). Or the 'wills' in God contradicting the end each one intends.

Comment: Let's say you have a child. As they reach adulthood your will of disposition towards them is that they will be happy and prosper. Your preceptive will is that you will tell them what to do to be happy and prosper. But your decretive will is that which you actually do towards them. These three don't necessarily have to be precisely the same; you wouldn't necessarily shower your child in whatever you think will make them happy and prosperous (as you may not have the capability), but you still will for them to be happy and prosperous and tell them that they should do certain things to attain it.

Comment: In much the same way God can will for everyone to be saved, without carrying out actions that result in everyone being saved. It is entirely reasonable and not contradictory to have a general desire for someone without yourself taking action to have that result occur.

Comment: @Abstractioniseverything. I'm not sure what you're saying here. What is God's purpose in contingency?

Comment: I found [this answer](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/52650/29840) to another question I posted, and it says we *deserve* punishment because of our "sin nature". If that is correct, do you think it should be included in this answer?

Comment: @anonymouswho I don't think it particularly adds to it, because our original sin causes us to sin by default, which still ends up with the same result: our sin deserves punishment.

Comment: Caleb doesn't seem to be saying that *original sin* "causes" us to sin. Not that he's denying that, but he seems to be saying that it doesn't matter whether we actually sin or not because Adam's supposed sin *is our* sin, and therefore we deserve punishment. Am I understanding that correctly?